# Can't invert hash to get feature names in vowpal wabbit w/ matrix factorization

Tags: vowpalwabbit, matrix-factorization

--invert_hash works fine with regression models, but when I activate matrix factorization the output is the same for both --readable_model and --invert hash. I'd like to see the latent variables for each user or item, but can't match them with the name of the item/user. Rather than show you all my full dataset, this small reproducible sample illustrates the problem:

```
#bash
echo "5 |u user1 |i item1
1 |u user1 |i item2
5 |u user2 |i item2
1 |u user2 |i item1" | vw -f test.vwbin --rank 2 

echo "5 |u user1 |i item1
1 |u user1 |i item2
5 |u user2 |i item2
1 |u user2 |i item1" | vw -t -i test.vwbin --invert_hash test.vwih

less test.vwih
```

The results look like:

```
Version 7.7.0
Min label:0.000000
Max label:5.000000
bits:18
0 pairs:
0 triples:
rank:2
lda:0
0 ngram:
0 skip:
options:
0 0.026660 0.029663 0.066095 0.001638 0.024027
1 0.004046 0.004133 0.001141 0.035247 0.077151
2 0.071812 0.048789 0.009294 0.078689 0.055306
... (and so on until line 262143)
```

None of these lines contain the strings 'user1', 'user2', 'item1', or 'item2'. Am I missing something?

One more question, I couldn't find the answer in the documentation - why are there 5 latent variables per event, since rank=2?